# Understanding threading synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading

The Fredrik Lundh article titled [*Thread Synchronization Mechanisms in Python*](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) gives the example below to show that multiple threads operating can result in an inaccurate value.

```
counter = 0

def process_item(item):
    global counter
    ... do something with item ...
    counter += 1
```

Then it goes on saying these things are thread-safe:

```
reading or replacing a single instance attribute
reading or replacing a single global variable
fetching an item from a list
modifying a list in place (e.g. adding an item using append)
fetching an item from a dictionary
modifying a dictionary in place (e.g. adding an item, or calling the clear method)
```

But isn't the code example just updating a single global variable, and hence would be thread-safe anyway?

What am I missing here?

Comment: "Updating" != "Replacing" Updating is dependent on prior state (so it's read, modify, write), replacing is not (it's just a write). Also note, technically modifying a `dict` in place is not always threadsafe in Python if the keys are user defined objects (because the `__eq__` or `__hash__` methods are invoked, and the GIL can be transferred to a different thread while they are executing, disrupting the atomicity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python the code:

```
counter += 1
```

is the same as saying:

```
counter = counter + 1
```

Thus the lookup of the value is separate to the update.

Comment: oh so count += 1 would be considered "reading and replacing" not "reading or replacing"?

Comment: @ealeon: `count += 1` is updating the value which requires reading its current value, changing it, and writing it back.